# When does the MLE have a p-value equal to 1?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimators, frequentist

Suppose we have data $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ that is independently and identically distributed from a distribution $\mathbb{P}_\theta$, with unknown parameter $\theta \in \Theta$.

Consider the hypothesis $H: \theta = \hat\theta_{MLE}$, and perform a two-sided significance test using a sufficient statistic of $\mathbb{P}_\theta$.

Sometimes, this will have a p-value of 1. For example, when  $X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\theta).$ In general, for what distributions will the hypothesis $H: \theta = \hat\theta_{MLE}$ have a p-value of 1?

Comment: Thanks Frans! Would you be able to clarify your comment? I'm trying to figure which distributions will result in the feature that the pointwise hypothesis that the parameter is equal to the MLE has a p-value of 1.

Comment: The thought was: if we were to suppose the null hypothesis was that the parameter is equal to whatever the MLE happens to be, would it be equal to 1? Can you explain the distinction between thinking about kinds of distributions, and the distributions of what?

Comment: Suppose the data has a mean of 0. If the hypothesis H: mu = 0 is considered, and a two sided statistical test is run on this data, the p-value will be 0.

Comment: Sorry! That was a typo. I meant the p-value will be 1. I'm trying to figure out for what distributions, it's guaranteed that a hypothesis about the MLE will result in a p-value of 1. The thought is that I'm trying to figure out when a hypothesis is optimal in once sense (it provides the MLE), it will also be optimal in another sense (it gives the data a low p-value.) These are equivalent for some distributions, and need to know which ones.

Comment: It's difficult to understand where you're coming from, because the claims in your question don't seem to make sense or be true.  For instance, when the test statistic has a continuous distribution, the null hypothesis is simple, and the test is admissible, then there is *zero* chance that the p-value will equal $1.$

Comment: The thought is: there are a few ways we could have a strong hypothesis, for some given data set. The hypothesis could be that the true parameter is equal to the maximum likelihood estimator, and no other hypothesis could make the data more likely. Or it could be that the p-value given the hypothesis is 1 -- no other value of the test statistic could be more likely the the one that was in fact observed. For some distributions, these hypotheses will always be the same. For a normal distribution, the sample mean is the MLE and the hypothesis that posits it will have a p-value of 1.